# Where are some of the most challenging airfields in the UK?

Tags: landing, airport, uk

I fly Microlights and am used to short strips, I can land at airfields such as Brown Shutters and Clench Common without much strain.

What are some of the most challenging airfields in the UK for light aircraft? I'm thinking the shortest runways with the most obstacles - I would like to improve more!

Comment: I'm not completely against list questions on Aviation, but note they have historically been considered bad on the SE Network https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139618/are-list-questions-off-topic

Comment: And our own previous discussion on list questions: https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3845/what-should-we-do-with-list-questions - As discussed, a single community wiki answer will be enforced here.

Comment: Seems like a caveat is needed here that this is only recommended for experienced pilots and that beginners should stick to the big, wide, long, no obstacle runways until they're pretty darn good at those landings... But, IANAP, so what do I know.

Comment: @FreeMan It depends what you learn on. I did all of my training on a 350m grass strip... so I'm alright at short runways despite not being very experienced. Jamiec - noted :)

Comment: Might I suggest we widen this question to "The world" and have one CW per country....we might see some more interesting info

Comment: Do sheep count as obstacles?  You need to phone ahead at Gigha to make sure they're off the runway.  Never flown there myself but I've heard the surface is a bit challenging.

Comment: Tangential, but I absolutely love that there are difficult-to-land-at airfields named "Brown Shutters" and "Clench Common" :)

Comment: @AakashM haha yep, they're tough. Someone crashed into power lines at brown shutters back in August - https://aviation-safety.net/wikibase/344844

Answer (score 2):

<sub>This sort of question is more interesting when we don't narrow it down to one country but have one answer per country. In that spirit, this answer is for:</sub>

---

## United Kingdom

**Short**

There are a number of airfields with very short runways, probably one of the shortest *licensed* runways is [Netherthorpe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netherthorpe_Airfield) at 382m (LDA 308m)

*Unlicensed* you'll have a few to pick from. Grass runway at [Gloucestershire Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gloucestershire_Airport) is 305m

---

**Challenging**

Often quoted as challenging is [Barra](https://www.hial.co.uk/barra-airport) which is the only airfield situated on a public beach.

---

**Honourable Mention**

It's unclear whether this airfield is still open, it's not shown on any guides, but one of the most challenging airfields must be [Vallance-By-Ways](https://www.abct.org.uk/airfields/airfield-finder/vallance-by-ways/). It is situated a couple of hundred meters from Gatwick Airport's runway. You can watch a (pretty scary) [video](https://youtu.be/stAWFL7ydZk?si=S3cThycfLmJGetR_) of someone landing a microlight there.

Comment: I'm sure there are many many more challenging airfields in the UK, but this is a start on the most often quoted ones that I know of. I hope others can/will contribute.